# A detail on Lusin's theorem

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $B$ is a ball of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, $(m\geq2)$, and $f(x)$ a measurable function on $B$. According to Lusin's theorem, we can find a closed set $F\subset B$ whose complement has a measure as small as we wish and such that $f$ is continuous on $F$. My question is:  Is it possible that $F$ have an empty interior? If yes, can we find a closed set with no empty interior?

Comment: In general, $F$ will have empty interior. If $F$ has interior points, those are points of continuity of the unrestricted function.

Comment: For example, take $f$ to be the characteristic function of the set of points with rational coordinates.

Comment: So $F$ is compact (closed and bounded) without being locally compact?

Comment: Where did local compactness come from?  Every compact space is locally compact.

Comment: In this case, $F$ is a Baire Space, correct?

Comment: I clarify: We know that a locally compact space is a Baire space. Since $F$ is closed and bounded, it is compact and so locally compact. Can we conclude that $F$ is a Baire space?

Comment: I clarify: We know that a locally compact space is a Baire space. So here $F$ is closed and bounded so compact and also locally compact. Can we conclude that $F$ is a Baire space? If this is true, it is possible to prove that a measurable function is locally bounded at least at one point.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I got the answer. The set $F$ is closed and a Baire space  for the previously indicated reason. However, contrary to what I thought at first, the famous Baire category theorem doesn't imply that $f$ is locally bounded even at a single point. Thanks every one,Daniel Fischer, Steven Taschunk and  Nate Eldredge, for your help to understand the problem.